# Search related table in Laravel 8 using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, request

I'm trying to search related table laravel 8.

```
$searchdata = TableA::where('id', '>', '1')->with('TableB')->orderBy('name');

if (request()->get('search')) {
    $data = $data->where('name', 'LIKE', "%".request()->get('search')."%")
        ->orwhere('column1', "LIKE", "%".request()->get('search')."%")
        ->orwhere('column2', 'LIKE', "%".request()->get('search')."%");;
}

$data = $data->paginate(25);

return view('dashboard', compact('data')view('dashboard',compact('data')
```

It works like that. But I want to search also TableB.

**search.blade.php**

```
<form class="" method="GET" action="">
    <div class="form">
        <div class=" col-md-5 py-2 m-auto">
            <input type="text" name="search" value="{{request()->get('search')}}"
                   placeholder="Search Data" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Table**

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($data as $show)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$show->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$show->column1}}</td>
        <td>{{$show->column2}}</td>
        <td>
            <table class="table table-sm">
                @foreach ($show->TableB as $o)
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong> {{$loop->iteration}}-</strong>
                            {{$o->xyz}} -
                            {{$o->abc}} -
                            {{$o->zxc}} -
                            {{$o->qwe}} -
                        {{$o->mnb}}
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

How can I search in TableB in this situation? I try or where, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try joins for getting common data from both tables

Comment: How should i do that

Comment: Study a joins concept https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins and eager loading(with()) used for loading the relationship tables https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading